# What does this mean: Если он хоть что-нибудь буркнет, я за себя не ручаюсь

Tags: значения, идиомы

What is the meaning of this sentence? `Если он хоть что-нибудь буркнет, я за себя не ручаюсь.` I understand the literal meaning, or as Google Translate or DeepL translates it literally: `If he muttered anything, I wouldn't be able to defend myself.` However that doesn't really make sense in English. Can someone rephrase this in idiomatic English?

Comment: Normally, this site isn't meant to provide translations, but I'll add one below, which I hope you'll note before your query is taken down.

Comment: Could you provide more context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the absence of any context, my guess is this means: "If he blurts something out ('spills the beans'), I can't vouch for myself."

Another meaning of бу́ркнуть (impf. бурча́ть) is to grumble or growl, so the sentence might be read as "If he tries to complain / argue with me, I don't know what I might do (to him)."

"Я за себя не ручаюсь" is another idiom which literally means "I can't vouch for myself" and is often used as a threat ('I can't vouch that I won't hurt you') or simply to say "The deal is off", "All bets are off."

Comment: "я за себя не ручаюсь" - это точно не "I would't be able to guarantee what I said"

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ну почему же? "За себя" здесь скорее всего = "за свои слова", ручаться = vouch / guarantee.

Comment: "за себя" = "за свои действия"

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ОК, согласен. Убрал. Спасибо!

Answer (score 6):

In idiomatic English, that'd be:

> If he blabs one word (of this), I won't be responsible for my actions.